# A bag contains $3$ red and $2$ black balls . One ball is drawn at random . Its color is noted and put in the bag. A second draw is made and the same

Tags: combinatorics

A bag contains $3$ red and $2$ black balls . One ball is drawn at random . Its color is noted and put in the bag. A second draw is made and the same procedure is repeated . Find the probability of drawing two red balls.

Well, here goes my solution:

> The number of ways to select two red balls is $\binom{3}{2}$ . The total number of ways to choose two balls is $\binom{5}{2}$. The required probability is $3/10$.

However if we do this in the following way:

> We consider two events $A$: drawing a red ball at first draw and $B$: drawing a red ball at second draw. We know that, $P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are independent events. So, $P(A)=3/5=P(B)$ . So, $P(A\cap B)=9/25$.

The answer given as the solution is $9/25$. However , if we solve this taking into consideration that these two events are independent to each other , then we get a different answer than solving it in the "normal way"(i.e the 1st method). Which method is valid? Why is the other one not valid? Why is the problem occuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a question of one way or the other being "normal"

There are two *distinct* problems.

$\dfrac{\binom32}{\binom52}$ is for drawing **without** replacement

$\frac35\cdot\frac35$ is for drawing **with** replacement